# Interesting answer in a closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I have posted an answer to a question, and I really think the answer was good, as I received some up votes, and I really tried my best to answer the question.

It happens though the question has been closed, and I was wondering if opening a new question, pointing out an appropriate, and answering my own question, would be acceptable, considering the stack overflow policy rules.

Is it wrong for me to pose a new question and answer it by myself?

Here is the question I'm referring to, and my answer is there too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659107/how-to-create-combinators-lambda-calculus-of-data-structures

Comment: @Bart By being able to improve the question asked, do you mean I should edit the question? Can I edit a question even if it's closed?And would it be reopened then?

Comment: I have edited the question, and flagged it for reopening evaluation. Thanks for the prompt support!

Comment: The [edit that you've made](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13659107/3) doesn't actually improve the question, it just *adds words*. The fundamental question is still "Can someone give an example of a data structure definition, for example, a queue, or a stack, in which is shown the application of a fixed point combinator?" which is "Not Constructive". I appreciate that you're involved in this question, but frankly, you shouldn't answer, or try to improve questions like this in the first place; there simply is no good answer, nor is there any good way to make these good questions.

Comment: In other words, what is the [practical, answerable problem](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) here?  There is none, which is why we close very open ended, broad questions such as this.  Next time, please vote to close and flag for moderator attention.  There are much better questions to be answered on the site than this.

Comment: As for asking and answering a question yourself, it's perfectly ok to do so.  We even encourage it.  But it has to be a *quality* question. If it's the same as what you've already answered, then there's nothing of quality there (as per the previous comments).

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Thanks for your comments; I understand now why my edit is not enough for reopening the question. Do you think an edit like: "help building a stack data structure definition in lambda calculus" cause the question to be reopened? I guess this would not be a broad question as the former.

Comment: There's not really an edit that you can make in this situation.  With regards to the title, your title isn't any less broad than the original.  The question, even more generally than I've pointed out before is "do my work for me".  We don't favor those questions, and there's not really any way to improve them.  The edits that you're making are just information to help people who answer to do the work for the person asking the question, and we explicitly discourage that here.  You can't fabricate a problem that you know nothing about.

Comment: It's a great answer, but I'd stop worrying about the question being closed or opened.  If it's deleted, we can undelete it, but there's really no salvaging the question in my eyes.  Now, if you had a real, practical, answerable problem (perhaps how to do this with a sample of *what you've tried*), then *that* question can be asked.  And then we could close the original craptacular question as a duplicate of your new question, and then merge it, which would move your answer over and keep your rep on the answer intact.

Comment: In other words, craft a *quality* question that shows what the problem is (make one up, but make it a legitimate problem, it's harder than you think, trust me) that is also a duplicate, then comment at me here or flag for moderator attention to close as a duplicate, reference this meta question, and we'll merge your answer into your new question.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas More than I could expect, really! Thank very very much for your attention! I'll try to make a feasible question, and then I'll post a comment here for merging the question, if the question gets really acceptable. Once more, thank you very much for the patience in answering me. I've learned a lot here!

Comment: No problem.  Just make sure it's a good question that a) shows the problem b) shows *what you've tried* c) doesn't change your answer on the original question and d) the other question can be closed as a dupe of and then I'll take care of the rest.

Comment: @Jolly off topic, do you plan to revive your "community blog" suggestion at some point? I have a couple of ideas re what could be on-topic there. No hurry at all, just curious whether you withdrew it or just did a pit stop to reword it.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas I've posted a question which I hope obeys the four requirements a, b, c, and d, you've pointed. Here is the link to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015990/defining-a-stack-data-structure-and-its-main-operations-in-lambda-calculus

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Do you think the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015990/defining-a-stack-data-structure-and-its-main-operations-in-lambda-calculus complies the requirements you pointed? If you find it's good enough, could you merge the answer with the new post? Or even tell me what is lacking in the question I've written? Regards!

Comment: @Rubens Let me check...  Hold please.

Comment: @Rubens That's *awesome*.  Thank you.  I've merged everything and cleaned up both posts (as there was one or two continuity issues).  One request, don't put meta commentary in the post itself in the future.  It typically doesn't go over well with the community (I know you were trying to help, it's cool) depending on the situation.  Also, I deleted the comment from you on your question, as it was really more about the merge and not addressing the question posed to you.  You can feel free to answer that comment now in a more direct way.  Thanks, this is a great post!

Comment: @Pekka Reconsidering the whole thing, really.  I'm rather lax during the holiday season.  I took the feedback from the answers and comments on that post and am letting it mull in my head while I catch up on my own personal projects.

Comment: @Rubens And sorry I missed your comments from two days ago and didn't address this sooner, I get a lot of pings in my inbox.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Beautiful! Everything's so perfect now! (: Thank you very very much for your attention and patience! Now I'll show my friends the solution I've got for that question (: Thank you very much, and thanks everybody else who helped me in this process! ^^

Comment: @Rubens No problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't just ask a new question with the exact same answer. After all, you would more or less be creating an exact duplicate. Even if your question ends up being better.

Closed questions are not necessarily deleted. Especially if there is valuable content contained within the answers. To make sure this doesn't happen, you might want to improve the original question. After all, you seem to have a clear idea of what the OP tried to ask. So why not try to improve it to something that can stand up to scrutiny?

Once you've edited the question into shape, you can either see whether or not it gathers the necessary reopen votes. Or you could flag for moderator attention, explaining what you've done and ask for it to be considered for reopening.

Do make sure though that not any edit will mean the question gets reopened. It has to be a good question for the site, according to the site's rules. But if you think you can rephrase the question so it becomes a good one (in line with what the OP originally intended), why not give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much; I'm trying to rephrase the question, and then I'll flag the post as you said (:

Comment: Great, good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Asking and answering your own question [is actually encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). That's the 'blog' part of [this diagram](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315010258/http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/venn-diagram.png) that currently appears in the `/about` page of nearly every site in our network.

But, prior to doing what you're contemplating, ask yourself the following:

- Will your question lead more people to the solution they are looking for?
- Can the existing question just be edited and turned around, perhaps with some help from moderators? Am I just creating an (albeit better) duplicate?
- Could some of the answers from the poorly asked question sufficiently answer the one I want to write? (hint: edit instead)

We'd much prefer to have a *single* incarnation of each question. If you really feel that an existing, poorly asked question (and the answers it received) are blocking you from hitting a grand slam with a great canonical question and answer, involve us first by flagging.

In other words, if a train wreck is getting in your way, we'll *probably* help you by clearing the tracks. If you have some awesome stuff to share that has not been covered, you should *absolutely* feel free to share it as the blog post describes. Otherwise, involve us [moderators] for best results. We may need to have a quick chat prior to taking action, but we're here to help when it comes to things like this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer; I considered Bart solution, reasserted by your post, and I'm trying to improve the question, so that I may flag it later for reopening.

Comment: Flag if you run into trouble. Thanks for taking the time to make an improvement.